# libp2p - How to discover initial peers?

Tags: rust, libp2p

In the bitcoin p2p core client, the initial peers are found, as stated, as:

> When started for the first time, programs don’t know the IP addresses
> of any active full nodes. In order to discover some IP addresses, they
> query one or more DNS names (called DNS seeds) hardcoded into Bitcoin
> Core and BitcoinJ. The response to the lookup should include one or
> more DNS A records with the IP addresses of full nodes that may accept
> new incoming connections. For example, using the Unix ``dig command
> [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28Unix_command%29>`__](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28Unix_command%29%3E%60__):

source: https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/p2p_network.html

Is the same approach required for libp2p for initial peer discovery? I was not able to find any tutorial which covers this information. I was hoping libp2p would handle this problem. Does the libp2p provide guidance or facilities for this?

Comment: Not familiar with libp2p, but it's very unlikely it "solves" this problem. You will always need some hardcoded startpoint to request the state of the network from - there's simply no other way to obtain that information.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo while one of the ways is certainly a "hardcoded startpoint" another way libp2p does bootstrapping is via [mDNS](https://github.com/libp2p/specs/blob/master/discovery/mdns.md).

Comment: @Discordian mDNS only finds peers on the local network. It basically asks every single device on the network if its a peer, which isn't feasible on the whole internet. Regular DNS is also an option, but is still a "hardcoded" peer - if it goes away, there's no alternatives until the record is updated.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The statement was "you will *always* need some hardcoded startpoint" which I proved false. If an already bootstrapped peer is on the local network, it can be found and contacted via mDNS, and provide a list of peers it's currently connected to as a bootstrap list. I'll write a complete answer later.

Answer (score 1):

For libp2p peer discovery can be accomplished a variety of ways:

> Peer discovery can be done using various protocols, such as broadcasting a message to all peers in the network or using a bootstrap node to provide a list of known peers.

source: https://docs.libp2p.io/concepts/discovery-routing/overview/#peer-discovery

The most common ways to begin peer discovery are:

1. Hard-coded bootstrap list (details in [A Rusty Bootstrapper](https://blog.ipfs.tech/2023-rust-libp2p-based-ipfs-bootstrap-node/))
2. mDNS, for local peer discovery ([libp2p mDNS spec](https://github.com/libp2p/specs/blob/master/discovery/mdns.md))

Your node will connect to initial bootstrap peers, and ask them about what peers they're aware of, and try to connect to those peers until it's sufficiently "bootstrapped".